# A field drop down menu in a view appears in a different view

Tags: list-view, page-layout, dropdown, sharepoint-fields

I have created two views from the same list.  Both are on the same page.  The views are stacked on top of each other.  When I click to choose a selection from a a dropdown menu in the bottom view, the drop down menu appears in multiple fields in the top view?

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image?

Comment: How do I add an image?

Comment: Edit this post and ad a picture of you problem using the picture icon in the toolbar

Comment: Any idea why this would occur

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same issue here, where the end result was submitting a bug report to MS.  That wont get it fixed.(not fast anyway)  You will still need to figure out a work around.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f95c4a1a-fc2d-4d97-9d54-6c1fdb450501/rendering-error-when-using-more-than-one-datasheetview-on-a-enterprise-wikipage?forum=sharepointgeneral